# finding the missing number by pattern

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

In this riddle you need to find a pattern between every couple of numbers.

Given numbers $5$ and $10$ there is a pattern like in the numbers $10$ and $3$.

Given numbers $10$ and $15$ there is a pattern like in the numbers $6$ and $1$.

Given numbers $10$ and $6$ there is a pattern like in the numbers $x$ and $8$.

find $x$.

- the pattern is the same in all examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=20$
Since in first riddle  the numbers are 10 and 3 they are formed by $5×2$ & $5-2$ . In the second  numbers are 6 and 1 they are formed by $3×2$ &$3-2$ . From here $x=20$ gives the numbers 20 and 8 and they are formed by $10×2$ & $10-2$.

Comment: but what about the pattern in each line of the first couple of numbers? in the first couple maybe it's $5*1=5,5*2=10$ and then $5*2=10,5-2=3$. in the second line it's: $5*2=10,5*3=15$ then $3*2=6,3-2=1$ but in the third line it's $2*3=6,2*5=10$ and $10*2=20,10-2=8$ but it's not the same pattern..

Comment: The numbers we made the second couple with  are taken from first couple like the two lines above

Comment: but you didn't take the numbers of the first couple for making the second couple. for example in the first line you made $10,3$ by numbers $5,2$ not by $5,10$ which is the first couple. same goes for second line. you mad numbers $6,1$ by the couple $3,2$ and not by the first couple there which is $10,15$...

Comment: I used the factors of the first couples to find the second ones not their products

Comment: i see. hmm ok i guess it can be done like that. thank you

Comment: You are welcome ☺